# What made Win9x NotePad so stable?

Tags: windows, data-structures, text-editor, notepad

I'm pondering how to make a text editor very stable. In my experience, text editors are second only to games in exhibiting flaky behavior (hanging, corrupted files, etc.).

I haven't programmed for Windows, but I have maintained a lot of Windows machines since the mid 1990s, and it occurred to me that NotePad is perhaps the one application I have used a lot but have never had a problem with.

What about the design of the Windows 9x NotePad made it so stable? Did the very small file size limit (64 KB) allow a simpler internal structure?

Comment: Why do you think that the Win 9x Notepad is more stable than the Win NT-based versions?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Later versions removed the size limit and do seem to be less stable with very large files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons: it's pared down to the essentials, and it relies on the existing Windows text control for most of its functionality.

Comment: Very good summary. The Windows edit control is an *extremely* well-tested piece of software!

Comment: Not being familiar with Windows internals, I wouldn't have guessed that one. Still, that leaves me wondering about the Windows text control.